# Unable to start elastic search on Ubuntu AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, elastic-stack, elk

I have installed Elasticsearch on the AWS ec2 instance i forgot to stop the service and did the necessary config changes on "elasticsearch.yml" and after that, I restarted the service now facing an issue

```
Mar 07 12:31:11 ip-172-31-13-166 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit elasticsearch.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 07 12:31:11 ip-172-31-13-166 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 12:31:11 ip-172-31-13-166 systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1564 and the job result is failed.
Mar 07 12:31:11 ip-172-31-13-166 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 3.091s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
```